# simply need to copy program file notepad.exe from the \windows to the \tools directory using command prompt

Tags: command-line

attempting to copy program file notepad.exe from the \windows to the \tools directory using command prompt.  Trying to complete simple tasks using command prompt, but still unable to grasp.  have not found a set of instructions that clicks for me, very new to "computing"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the below command,

```
cp /path/to/notepad.exe /path/to/the/parent/directory/tools
```

The above command copy the notepad.exe file from the directory(according to yours) to your tools directory.

`/path/to/notepad.exe`  - full path of notepad.exe file

`/path/to/the/parent/directory/tools` - full path of tools directory

Run `man cp` for more details.

Comment: Thank you, and the explanation of command is super helpful!!!

Comment: The `cp` command is just a copy command - This: `cp "/path/to/source-file" "/path/to/destination-file"` would just copy first file ("/path/to/source-file") to the second files's ("/path/to/destination-file") location. The first `/` represents root, the names between the `/` are directory names. The last thing after the `/` can be a file or direcotry - if you also want to copy directories you need to specify it as `cp "/path/to/source-folder" "/path/to/destination-folder"`. **AvinashRag**, best to use quotes `"` if the folder path has spaces in.